# CMake can I filter compiler output through another program

Tags: cmake

Can I tell CMake to pipe all stderr output from the compiler and/or linker through an external program and showing the output of that on the terminal instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Makefile generators you can apply a filter to the compiler output by setting a custom launcher for compile rules. The following CMake list file sketches the necessary steps:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project (Main)

configure_file(
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/gcc_filter.sh.in"
    "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/gcc_filter.sh"
    @ONLY)

add_executable (Main Main.cpp)

set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/gcc_filter.sh")
```

In the project root directory add the following shell script template file `gcc_filter.sh.in`:

```
#!/bin/sh

# shell script invoked with the following arguments
# $(CXX) $(CXX_DEFINES) $(CXX_FLAGS) -o OBJECT_FILE -c SOURCE_FILE

# invoke compiler
exec "$@" 2>&1 | "@PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR@/myfilter.sh"
```

The actual shell script invoked by the custom launcher rule is first copied to the project binary directory with the `configure_file` call in the CMake list file. The executable bit of the file `gcc_filter.sh.in` must be set. The shell script forwards all arguments to the compiler and then pipes the compiler output to another shell script `myfilter.sh` in the project root directory:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec wc
```

The example `myfilter.sh` just invokes `wc` but more elaborate output filtering can be easily done using the above recipe.